Creating filter by priority is SQL query (Clickhouse)
I want to write a query that adds a new column by filtering through several other columns taking a value by priority.
The example is that I need to create a resulting column containing 0, 1 or -1, checking 3 other columns one by one. If my column 1 has 0 or 1, I write this in Resulting column, but if column 1 has -1, I should then check column 2 for 0 or 1, if there is also -1, then I check column 3 for 0 or 1, and write it down, and if there is no 0 or 1, I write -1 to the resulting column.
Hope the task is clear.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current query attempt.

Take a look at the multiIf function

Good suggestions above, and also be sure to use a table engine in ClickHouse designed for updating rows - ReplacingMergeTree or CollapsingMergeTree (or Versioned options of each) would be the most common choices https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/collapsingmergetree
